# Conditional convergence of $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ and $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty} \log(1+a_n)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

In the Ahlfors Complex Analysis book section on infinite products, there is a result that the the series $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty} |a_n|$ converges exactly when $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty} | \log(1+a_n)|$ does.
Ahlfors then makes the remark that there is in general no relationship when convergence is only conditional: One of $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ and $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty} \log(1+a_n)$ might converge when the other does not.

He says there are *simple* examples but doesn't give any, so I tried to come up with a couple myself.

I think I managed to squeak out a couple, and the idea seemed to boil down to looking at the first three terms in the series expansions for $\log(1+z)$ and $\exp(z)-1$ near $z=0$:

$$
\text{(A) } \log(1+z) = z - \frac{1}{2}z^2 + z^3\left(\frac{1}{3} + [z]\right)  \\
\text{(B) } \exp(z)-1 = z + \frac{1}{2}z^2 + z^3\left(\frac{1}{6} + [z]\right)
$$

Then you use $z_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}$, so that the $z$ term is alternating, the $z^2$ term is like $\frac{1}{n}$, and the $z^3$ term is like $n^{-\frac{3}{2}}$.

Use (A) to get $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ to converge and $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty} \log(1+a_n)$ to diverge.
Use (B) for the other way around.

**Question:** Am I thinking straight here?

Comment: Very straight towards the canonical examples.